# Loop through ALL regex capture groups in AHK

Tags: autohotkey

I have a [Match Object](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/RegExMatch.htm#MatchObject) capture group setup in a regexmatch. I am taking a comma-separated list of items and trying to convert it into an array. So my plan was to find the total matches and just loop through the matches and add quotes (unsure of an easier way to do this).

My problem is that I don't know what the total number of matches found are. Is there a way to check how many values are matched? I have a staged variable named `max_index`

```
lab_list_array := []
haystack := "lab.website.int, abc.demo.company.com, product.eu.company.com, 10.199.1.1"
regexmatch(haystack,"O)(([a-zA-Z0-9-]{1,63}\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,63}|\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3}.\d{1,3})",lab_list)
loop, %max_index%
  {
    lab_list_array := "" lab_list[A_index] "" 
    if [A_index] != %max_index%
      {
        lab_list_array .= ","
      }
  }
```

Please let me know if this is the wrong way of building this array and you would do it differently.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find some answers after searching further,
you can easily find the max index of the array by doing this... [reading on it is here](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/Object.htm)

```
; Returns the length of a linear array.
max_index := lab_list.length()
```

But a better way to build this array or convert the string to an array would be the usage of `loop, parse, haystack, CSV`

```
lab_list_array := []
loop, parse, haystack, CSV, " `t" 
  {
    lab_list_array.Push(A_Loopfield)
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, the simplest way to achieve this, given the example you provided, would be to use the StrSplit() function.

```
haystack := "lab.website.int, abc.demo.company.com, product.eu.company.com, 10.199.1.1"
lab_list_array := StrSplit( haystack, "," )
Msgbox  %   lab_list_array.Count() ; could be lab_list_array.Lenght() also
Loop,% lab_list_array.Count()
    Msgbox  %   lab_list_array[A_Index]
ExitApp, 0
```